# TIdAntiFreeze Implementation

Tags: c++, indy10

Under Delphi XE8's FormCreate, i am using the following syntax to apply the AntiFreeze function:

```
if Assigned(AntiFreeze) then FreeAndNil(AntiFreeze);

// or sometimes: AntiFreeze := TIdAntiFreeze.Create(NIL);
```

I trying to implement it in C ++ Builder XE8, like this:

```
   if (AntiFreeze->Assign()) {
     AntiFreeze->Active;
     AntiFreeze->Free();
   }
```

But it does not work. I need help you to tell me the correct way.

Thank you so much..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Delphi code is freeing a `TIdAntiFreeze` component that has been placed on the Form at design-time.  If you don't want the component, don't put it on the Form in the first place.

That being said, the C++ equivalent of the Delphi code would be:

```
if (AntiFreeze) FreeAndNil(AntiFreeze);

// or sometimes: AntiFreeze = new TIdAntiFreeze(NULL);
```

That being said, you really should strive to not use `TIdAntiFreeze` at all.  You should not be doing *anything* in the context of the main UI thread that blocks the main message loop for more than a few seconds at most.  Most Indy operations are better suited for use in worker threads instead of the main UI thread.  `TIdAntiFreeze` only works in the main UI thread, by pumping the main message loop while Indy operations are blocking the main thread.

Comment: My another question, which is better to put those codes in `FormCreate` or in `(TComponent* Owner): TForm(Owner)`. Thank you Remy.

Comment: @July: That should have been posted as a new question. In any case, NEVER use the Form's `OnCreate` event in C++, as it can cause illegal behavior if/when called by the base class `TCustomForm` constructor before your derived Form's constructor is called. ALWAYS use the derived Form's actual constructor instead. Delphi does not suffer from this problem because its object creation model is opposite of C++'s creation model. If you want more details, post a new question about it.